# Can I reuse variables or objects that I delete?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure this out but can't quite get my head round it.

Say I declare an object in a header file such as:

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#include "otherclass.h"

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    OtherClass *obj;
};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

Can I do the following in my code?

```
obj = new OtherClass();

//Do something

delete obj;

obj = new OtherClass();

//Do something else

delete obj;
```

Or would I have to create a new `obj`?

I can't really think of a reason why I might need to do this but I'd like to know if it would work and also whether or not it would be a good idea (I know it's best to create objects on the stack generally but for the sake of argument let's say in this case it isn't an option).

Comment: After an instance was deleted you can't _'reuse'_ it. Create a new instance if you need one afterwards.

Comment: You can reuse the _pointer_, the object itself has been destroyed.

Comment: Your question makes little sense, perhaps because you have mixed up some concepts. First, your header doesn't declare any objects. It declares a class. Next, what does it mean to "create a new `obj`"? `obj` is the name of a variable. You can't create a new one.

Comment: You could do what you propose because `new OtherClass();` is creating a new `obj` and therefore a new pointer to it. Also if in`SomeClass` the `OtherClass` member is just a pointer forward declare it instead.

Comment: The answer to your question title is "no". The answer to your question body is "yes, this is perfectly correct". The reason for the difference is that what you're actually doing is assigning values to a pointer variable. The pointer variable (the pointer, in short) is never deleted. What it points to is deleted. The pointer variable can still be used for other purposes.

Comment: Simply speaking what you are doing is fine, `obj` is just a a holder of the value that `new OtherClass()` returns that you are storing in `obj` when you `delete obj` you are deleting the object pointed to by `obj`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to adjust your mental model of what's happening. Let's look at a simpler case where we don't have the `SomeClass` class:

```
int main() {
  OtherClass *obj = new OtherClass();
  delete obj;
  obj = new OtherClass();
  delete obj;
}
```

The first line is this function is a *declaration*. This declaration introduces an object called `obj` whose type is `OtherClass*`. The important thing here is that `obj` is *just* a pointer. It's not an `OtherClass` object. It just holds the address of one. So when you talk about the object `obj`, you are talking about the pointer.

This declaration has an *initialiser* which is `= new OtherClass()`. The *expression* `new OtherClass()` also introduces an object, but this time it is not named. This object has type `OtherClass`. The expression returns a pointer to that `OtherClass` object which you are using to initialise `obj`. So now the `obj` pointer object is pointing at the `OtherClass` object.

The memory model for this looks something like this:

```
      obj
+-------------+      +------------+
| OtherClass* |----->| OtherClass |
+-------------+      +------------+
```

Now, you can use an object during its lifetime. The lifetime of `obj` is the scope of the function we declared it in. At the end of the function, `obj` goes out of scope and is destroyed. That is, the *pointer* is destroyed. The lifetime of the `OtherClass` object lasts up until we use `delete` on a pointer to it. The `delete` only destroys the `OtherClass` object and not the pointer. So after the first `delete`, we have this:

```
      obj
+-------------+
| OtherClass* |----->
+-------------+
```

The pointer still exists. It's still pointing to the same place even, but the object that was there is now gone.

At this point, we can't attempt to use the `OtherClass` object, since it doesn't exist any more. However, we can certainly reuse the pointer object `obj`. When we do `obj = new OtherClass()` (which is an expression, not a declaration), we create a new `OtherClass` object and set `obj` to point at it. We're back to this situation:

```
      obj
+-------------+      +------------+
| OtherClass* |----->| OtherClass |
+-------------+      +------------+
```

And then we `delete` it again.

The only difference between this example and your example is that `obj` is a member of `SomeClass`. Each object of type `SomeClass` will contain within it an `OtherClass*` pointer called `obj`. The lifetime of `obj` now is whatever the lifetime of the `SomeClass` object is. As long as that object is still alive, you can use `obj` in whatever way you like. Of course, if you `delete` the object it is pointing at, you cannot use that object.

Comment: but.. how much free time do you have!! (:

Comment: Thanks, this was the most informative answer for me

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ok.

If you want you can reuse your pointer any time you want.

```
obj = new OtherClass();
delete  obj;
obj = new OtherClass();
```

remeber that when you call delete you call OtherClass destructor.

it is good practice, but not required, put pointer to zero after delete.

```
obj = 0;
```

This because, if after delete pointer you want to test, for instance

```
if(!obj) {
   ...
}
```

it is said that !obj == true.

Comment: If c++11 is available would setting the pointer to `nullptr` be better?

Comment: Whether setting the pointer to null is a good idea or not depends on whether you have code which is conditioned on whether the object is present or not (e.g. a cached object, where you delete when the cache is invalidated); it's generally _not_ a good idea.  And to test whether the pointer is null: `if ( obj == nullptr )`.  No need to obfuscate.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, but in C++11 consider using unique_ptr to avoid having to call "delete" manually. Eg:

```
std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> obj(new OtherClass());

//Do something

obj.reset(new OtherClass()); //this deletes the previous object

//Do something else. The object will be deleted when obj goes out of scope.
```

Also you might want to consider changing your title to something like, "Can I reassign a pointer after deleting the object it points to?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work. When you do the second

```
obj = new OtherClass();
```

the obj points to deleted memory, but you set it to new value. There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

Depending on how `OtherClass` works, you may consider doing:

```
obj = new OtherClass();

//Do something

// then do something else

delete obj;
```

But this is not always feasible. Should this not be applicable in your case, what you are currently doing is OK.

I'd just do `obj = NULL;` after the second `delete`. Just in case I need to test this pointer's value somewhere else, to determine whether it is in use or not.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up : you can't use an instance of a class that has been deleted, but you can reuse the variable pointer which was used to store the address of the instance.

That is to say, you CANNOT do the following (from your code sample) :

```
obj = new OtherClass();
delete obj;

obj->objMethod(); // dereferencing a now invalid pointer => dangerous.
```

But you can do what you wrote in your question :

```
obj = new OtherClass();

//Do something
delete obj;

obj = new OtherClass();
//Do something else

delete obj;
```

Actually, the last sample of code is as valid as the following (with a simple `int`) :

```
int i = 42;
// Do something
i = 15;
// Do something
```